# Method input parameter as namespace

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

Let's say I have these objects

```
namespace MyResponses.Interfaces.IInterface1
{
    partial class exResponse
    {
        Object1 myObj; 
        bool flag;
    }
}

namespace MyResponses.Interfaces.IInterface2
{
    partial class exResponse
    {
        Object2 myObj;
        bool flag;
    }
}

namespace MyResponses.Interfaces.IInterface3
{
    partial class exResponse
    {
        Object3 myObj; 
        bool flag;
    }
}
```

And I need a method to check the flags in all exResponse objects.
This method would receive an object inside MyResponses.Interfaces namespace.

Something like:

```
bool CheckFlagInResponse(MyResponses.Interfaces response, Type responseType)
{
    return (response as responseType).flag;
}
```

I would call it like this?

```
CheckFlagInResponse(myExResponse, myExResponse.GetType())
```

Comment: What do you mean by "these objects"? Do you mean you actually have three different *types*, all called `exResponse` and all with a `flag` field or property? First, I'd avoid doing that.

Comment: Well all these are different responses from different web services that were not implemented by me :)

Comment: I'm confused about what is a namespace, what is a type and what is a member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like this is basically broken by design, if you have very similar types all with the same members (and even the same simple name) but with no type relationship between them.

If this is generated code and the types are all declared as `partial` types in the generated code, you could potentially fix this by making them all implement an interface:

```
public interface IFlag
{
    bool Flag { get; }
}

namespace MyResponses.Interfaces.IInterface1
{
    public partial class ExResponse : IFlag {}
}

namespace MyResponses.Interfaces.IInterface2
{
    public partial class ExResponse : IFlag {}
}

// etc
```

Then you can just use `IFlag` for anything that needs to access the flag - all the response classes would implement the interface.

Alternatively, if you *really* have to (and if you're using .NET 4, which it now sounds like you're not), you could just use dynamic typing:

```
bool CheckFlagInResponse(dynamic response)
{
    return response.flag;
}
```

Comment: I updated my question.. dunno if it will help

Comment: dynamic statement wouldn't work since I'm using .NET 3.5

Comment: @HélderGonçalves: In future, please make constraints like that clear in the question. It sounds like the partial class approach would work though.